# Pandas joining one column on 2 keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a DataFrame which contains the start station id and the end station id for a bike trip. I have another DataFrame which contains the station id and it's name. I would like to join these two tables to and add the following columns to the first one: 'end_station_name' and 'start station name'. My idea was to do the following:

```
stations_df.rename(columns = {'stationId': 'start_station_id'}, inplace=True)
stations_df['end_station_id'] = stations_df['start_station_id']
df.merge(stations_df)
```

This only gives me one station name per trip. How can I do to get both?
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should add keys to your merge method. Here is an example:

df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')

Link to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)